# How to turn off strictpopulate in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can you populate something that is not in the schema?
Mongoose is throwing the error `Cannot populate path 'example' because it is not in your schema. Set the 'strictPopulate' option to false to override.`

I tried adding `strictPopulate: false` to the Schema and the query. Both didn't work.

Comment: You can just create a virtual, this allows you to populate a value missing in your schema

Comment: My schema is kind of dynamic. So, I don't think virtuals will solve the problem.

Comment: If its dynamic you can try using Discriminators)

Answer (score 5):

It seems this works for me

```js
document.populate([{ path: keyString, strictPopulate: false }]);
```

Comment: After a three days struggle found this - Perfect !!!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a product `orderItem` inside `orderList`. You can't populate producy when reading `orderList`, instead you can use:

```
.populate({ path: "orderItems", populate: "product" });
```